# Are there any patterns to refactor a complex code without having to know exactly what that code does?

Tags: refactoring

I often find myself having a hard time trying to refactor some legacy code we have at work, because of the high complexity and all it's potential problems when touching that code. And to know exactly what that code does, takes a lot of time and effort, something I don't usually have.

So I was thinking, are there any patterns that could be used for this?, like, refactoring something without knowing what the entire code does?.

I've heard about some wrapper-like patterns, but some times they fall short.

Any ideas or best practices are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

However you spin it, changing code that you do not fully understand is always a risk. However, there are systematic refactoring methods available that will make changes in the code less risky and here I'm mostly thinking about *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler [on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672).

Also see https://refactoring.guru for the catalogue of refactorings discussed in the book. I would strongly recommend to use unit tests while refactoring, and do it step by step in small increments, divide and conquer. If you read the book and study the catalogue, you will see opportunities for small, safe refactorings even in messy, hard to read code.

If you are looking for a pattern, the best pattern for this type of problem is probably the Facade pattern where you dress up the legacy in nice clothes (the facade) and your client code communicates with the facade which in turn communicates with the sub system (legacy).

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Any provably correct code transformation is arguably a refactoring.
You don't have to know anything about code to apply such a transformation; by
definition it can't break your code.

For instance:

```
   "if (!\xx) { } else { \stmts } " ==>  "if (\x) { \stmts } "
```

is clearly correct and always safe to apply.

Now, whether *you* are able to apply such transformations reliably is another matter.  If the transformation is correct, and applied by a mechanically accurate transformation engine (see [Program Transformation Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) for such engines), then the result is correct.  What usually happens is people try to do this by hand... and they are lousy at managing detail, often breaking the code (thus the suggestion about unit testing).

Whether that transformation is an *improvement* is rather a matter of taste.  But if you believe in traditional code metrics, transformations that reduce line count,  operator count or branching is usually a win.   This applies to the example transformation above.

By using a mechanical engine, one can build up a big library of correct transforms and just apply them.

Comment: I was talking more about poorly designed entire set of classes and high level architecture that should be redefined, like decoupling refactors of the like. How can I refactor non-trivial code without knowing exactly what that code does?.

Comment: How can you say the class structure is poorly defined, if you don't have an idea of what "well defined" class structure is?   If you *can* define "well-defined" class structure, then you can define transformations to rearrange the code to bring it closer to your notion.   The problem here is you providing a mechanically interpretable definition, and then providing correct-transforms to re-shape the code.  Notice that I did not say "understand the code" anywhere in this.  You can convert a goto-mess program into a goto-free one without understanding it; you can change a class-mess similarly.

Comment: Why do you assume I don't have an idea of what a well defined class structure is?.

Comment: I assumed you did. I stated it that way to force a reasonable person into agreeing they did. Consequence: you can define some transforms that improve the class structure. My point is that applying such transforms reliably don't require anybody to "understand" the program at all.